# How do I horizontally center a fixed div while having the width fit the content inside

Tags: html, css, centering

I need the navigation bar on my website to stay horizontally centered on the page while having the `position: fixed;` property and I need the width to always be the same as the content inside the div

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Here is the CSS I have now:

```css
.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #505050;
    padding: 0;
    width: fit-content;
    border-radius: 15px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    margin-left: 280px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Here is [my website](https://spidergamin.github.io/SpiderGaming-Website) if you need that to see what I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `margin-left` in code.

Set `transform` and `left` for horizontally center.

Modify `width` to 100%.

```
.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #505050;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 15px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    left: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I needed.

Comment: I'm happy to help you. If the answer is helpful, you can vote the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add a wrapper around your tab

```
<div class="tabwrapper">
    <div class="tab">
    </div>
</div>

<style>
.tabwrapper {
   position: fixed;
   width: 100%;
   text-align: center;
   top: 0;
}

.tab {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to add a flexbox wrapper around your element and fix its position:

```css
.tab-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border: solid red 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 10;
}

.tab {
    padding: 0;
    border: solid blue 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class='tab-wrapper'>
  <div class='tab'>
    Content
  </div>
</div>
```

Borders added for visual clarity.